# How do I revert to the English keyboard after switching to Devanagari?

Tags: interactive, keyboard-layout

I do this to switch to a Hindi keyboard:-

```
C-x RET C-\ [TAB]
```

and then I choose :

```
devanagari-inscript
```

My query is : How do I switch back to an English keyboard? I can see options for english-dvorak and various latin-* keyboards, but which is the default English keyboard ? Can someone please clarify? Is there a way to display the current keyboard ? I tried

```
C-h I
```

but it says

```
No input method is activated now.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just use `C-\` to toggle the input method (and I recommend `C-u C-\` instead of `C-x RET C-\`).

Comment: My query is : what is the name of the default input method ?

Comment: Depends if you mean "the input method enabled at startup" (there isn't any) or "the input method activated if I just hit `C-\`" (in which case it is the last input method used, or some input method chosen based on your locale, IIRC).

Comment: I mean the input method at startup. How can I go back to that ?

Comment: As I said: `C-\\`

Comment: It works fine. Thank you.

Comment: Is this a typing mistake ? "the input method activated if I just hit `C-`" , did you mean `C-\`?

Comment: I can see some issues in the rendering of quoted strings here. C-\ ( which within back ticks ) is rendering as C-